# How to mass-change index field text in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

Let's say I created dozens of index entries with value {XE "foo"}. Now I decide that I want to change that to {XE "fooz"}. Is there any way to do a mass search and replace to do this?

I tried searching for

```
 ^d XE "foo"
```

and sure, it finds it. But if I try to say to replace it with

```
^d XE "fooz"
```

I get an error that ^d is not allowed in the replace field. If instead I just say to replace it with

```
XE "fooz"
```

then it's no longer an index entry but just plain text.

So is there any way to put an index field value in the "replace" box?

I'm using Home & Office 2010 version of Word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you can see the XE fields (CTRL SHIFT 8).  Then just do a normal find and replace.  Find:  XE "foo" and Replace with:  XE "fooz"

Comment: Ooh, this works. The trick is to NOT put ^d or braces in the Find box. This could give false hits if you had XE "foo" (or whatever word of course) as text, but that seems fairly unlikely.

Comment: You could minimise the false hits, by adding to your find the formatting condition that Font = Hidden text.

Comment: Ignore my comment above - although it looks like hidden text on screen with dotted underlining, the XE entries aren't hidden text after all.  Luckily XE isn't a word so you're right, you shouldn't get any false find results.

Answer (score 2):

First, manually make the change from `foo` to `fooz` inside just one of the `XE` fields, and then select the whole field code (including braces), and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.

Then, in the **Find and Replace** dialog box, in the **Find what** field, type `^d XE "foo"` as you did before. Then move the cursor into the **Replace with** field, and either select **Special** > **Clipboard Contents** or just type `^c`.

Comment: Fair enough, that ought to work. I was hoping for something a little more streamlined, but ...